# Equal spacing around UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, gridview, layout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to have equal amount of spacing between all the cells as well as between the screen border and the closest cell. Basically something like this. Equal spacing in and all around.

[image]

I managed to test this in the interface builder by setting values like this. I set the *cell size* to 110, *Min spacing* to 0 and all *Section Insets* to 10.

[image]

And it looks perfect in the IB.

[image]

However when I run it (in an iPad Air 2), it looks like this.

[image]

Notice the spacing in between the cells is bigger. I also tried to do this solely from the code by implementing the following methods from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 110, height: 110)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

That yielded the same results. Can anybody please tell me how to correct this? I'd prefer to do this by code. But I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Unluckily, this is how `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` works by default. That's because you specify exact section insets but minimum interitem space.
To do what you're asking, you mainly have two ways to do it depending on the end result you wish for. Both have to be done manually by code.

• Enlarge the cells to leave the exact space (same space, bigger cells)

• Compute the space and change the insets to match it (same cells, bigger space)

Both can be done by either setting the values on the layout object (and invalidating it) or by returning the values through the delegate.